# Constantly version bumping firebase-core in build.gradle. Best way to include firebase-core?

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, build.gradle

In `app/build.gradle` file I feel I constantly have to version bump Firebase-core. I have included Firebase as the setup suggests.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
  compile project(':react-native-locale')
  compile project(':react-native-fs')
  compile project(':react-native-view-shot')
  compile project(':react-native-share')
  compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
  compile project(':react-native-spinkit')
  compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
  compile project(':react-native-device-info')
  compile project(':react-native-camera')
  compile project(':react-native-sqlite-storage')
  compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
  compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.5@aar') { transitive = true; }
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
  compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
  compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0'

  // Getting a "Could not find" error? Make sure you have
  // added the Google maven respository to your root build.gradle
}

// ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

When the version is not up to date the compilation will fail with the error.

```
Dex: Error converting bytecode to dex:
Cause: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzfgf;
    UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
    com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzfgf;
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
        at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:502)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:334)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:277)
        at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:245)
        at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)

:app:transformClassesWithDexForProdDebug FAILED
```

Is there a better way to include fireabse?

Comment: Post all your dependencies

Comment: I've updated my post with the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way I have come to realize...

In the root `build.gradle` I now define a variable

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
 ext {
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "16.+"
    }
```

Then in the application's `build.gradle

```
dependencies {
  implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:${rootProject.ext.googlePlayServicesVersion}"

}
```

It is a little hacky because you are getting the latest version for minor versions/

Comment: Don't use the version codes like this: "16.+" because later if google release a new version which doesn't compatible with your code you won't know what is happened...